# Xamarin Webview executing javascript

Tags: android, xamarin, base64

I have this as my webviewclient

```
webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
        webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass());
        webView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.ClearCache(true);
        WebSettings websettings = webView.Settings;
        websettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        websettings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
        //webView.LoadUrl(ip_address + tablet_dir + "tk_tab_main.html");
        webView.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/tablet/tk_tab_main.html");





internal class WebViewClientClass : WebViewClient
    {
        //Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView.
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
        {
            string test = url;
            if (url.EndsWith("tk_tab_work_code.html"))
            {

                Bitmap photo = GetQRCode("in");
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    photo.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
                    byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
                    string base64_str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                    string image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64_str;
                    string script = "javascript:SetPhoto('" + image + "');";
                    photo.Recycle();
                    view.LoadUrl(url);
                    if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
                    {
                        view.EvaluateJavascript("SetPhoto('" + image + "');", null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        view.LoadUrl(script);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
```

After the url is loaded I want the setphoto javascript to run with the image string. Is there any solution to this? Setphoto function only changes the image src with the base64 string.

Comment: Have your pictures not been displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```
        public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
        {
              string test = url;
            if (url.EndsWith("tk_tab_work_code.html"))
            {

                Bitmap photo = GetQRCode("in");
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    photo.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
                    byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
                    string base64_str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                    string image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64_str;
                    string script = "javascript:SetPhoto('" + image + "');";
                    photo.Recycle();

                    if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
                    {
                        view.EvaluateJavascript("SetPhoto('" + image + "');", null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        view.LoadUrl(script);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```